# Scraping URLs in Beautiful Soup but not getting all links

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is the relevant part of the html, that is being scraped:

```html
<div class="blockSpoiler-content">
   <div class="contentSpoiler">
      <div class="link-box" id="62H" style="background-color: rgb(65, 120, 50);">
         <div class="status-box"><i class="working" title="Working"></i></div>
         <a rel="external" href="https://url1.net.html" target="_blank">Link1</a>
      </div>
      <div class="link-box" id="IFA" style="background-color: rgb(65, 120, 50);">
         <div class="status-box"><i class="working" title="Working"></i></div>
         <a rel="external" href="https://url2.net.html" target="_blank">Link2</a>
      </div>
      <div class="link-box" id="ruG" style="background-color: rgb(65, 120, 50);">
         <div class="status-box"><i class="working" title="Working"></i></div>
         <a rel="external" href="https://url3.com.html" target="_blank">Link3</a>
      </div>
      <div class="link-box" id="Bdf" style="background-color: rgb(65, 120, 50);">
         <div class="status-box"><i class="working" title="Working"></i></div>
         <a rel="external" href="https://url4.com" target="_blank">Link4</a>
      </div>
      <div class="link-box" id="1Da" style="background-color: rgb(65, 120, 50);">
         <div class="status-box"><i class="working" title="Working"></i></div>
         <a rel="external" href="https://url5.net.html" target="_blank">Link5</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get these URLs:

1. https://url1.net.html
2. https://url2.net.html
3. https://url3.com.html
4. https://url4.com
5. https://url5.net.html

I tried different things, but only got till here
(local file being used only for the purpose of testing, before web scraping):

```
with open("mainLocalFile.html") as fp:
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')
links = soup2.find_all('div', class_='blockSpoiler-content')
# print(links)
for link in links:
    print(link)
    print(link.a)          # prints only the first tag
    print(link.a['href'])  # prints only the first URL
```

Answer (score 1):

Select all `<a>` which are under tag with class `blockSpoiler-content` (now you're only selecting one `<div class=blockSpoiler-content>` with the `.find_all` method):

```py
for a in soup.select(".blockSpoiler-content a"):
    print(a["href"])
```

Prints:

```
https://url1.net.html
https://url2.net.html
https://url3.com.html
https://url4.com
https://url5.net.html
```